# Problema con collapse

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular, bootstrap

En un proyecto con Angular y Bootstrap, tengo un menú que esta debajo de un `carousel`, cuando la página refresca en una vista que no sea el `home`, el `carousel` no se oculta a menos que le ponga un `settimeout`.

Por ejemplo, si yo entro a  `http://localhost:4200/nosotros` el `carousel` no se oculta, claro esto se logra cuando le pongo un `settimeout`, pero yo quisiera que esté oculto desde el principio, sin ningún efectom solo el `navbar` arriba. Pero, si la página la empiezas desde `http://localhost:4200/home` todo estaría perfecto.

Nota: El código lo puse como referencia Angular, es una aplicación SPA y tiene un sistema de rutas. Sólo puse lo mas importante.

```js
 $(function () {
    $('#carouselx').collapse({
      hide: true
    })
    var ruta = "";
    var ruta = window.location.pathname;
    console.log(ruta)
    if(ruta!='/home'){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#carouselx').collapse('hide');
      },500 //nota no quiero depender de esta función para que se oculte por que hace un efecto extraño
      // si le pongo un $('#carouselx').hide() se oculta pero al darle click a  la vista home ya no
      // el carousel ya no aparece
      )

    }
    $('.nav-link').on('click', function () {

      var ru = window.location.pathname

      console.log(ru);
      if (ru != '/home') {
        $('#carouselx').collapse('hide');
      } else if(ru=='/home'){
        $('#carouselx').collapse('show');
      }
    })

  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselx" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/xcarousel1.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/xcarousel2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/xcarousel3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```